# What is the cmd to setup sourcetree with diffmerge for 3-way merges?

Tags: git, diffmerge, atlassian-sourcetree

While browsing I found some hints on how to invoke a 3-way merge for diffmerge:

- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/156961/setting-up-custom-merge-tool-in-sourcetree
- http://twobitlabs.com/2011/08/install-diffmerge-git-mac-os-x/

But nothing as simple as a command that should sit in sourcetree's configuration and just works:
[image]

If anyone has this setup, can you share?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `merge.conflictstyle` [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) setting. If you'd like to apply this setting to all of your repositories, run:

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure this is what @pulkitsinghal was looking for. What's the appropriate etiquette here? I'll leave this up long enough for him to comment on before I delete this answer.

Comment: If I use this approach, then does that mean when there is a manual merge for me to perform, the diffmerge tool will start itself off in a 3-way-merge style without the need for me to configure the `merge command setting` ?

Comment: I don't know. It changes the conflict style in text form. I don't if DiffMerge will notice. Here's what diff3 looks like: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_conflicts_are_presented

Comment: this doesn't look like it should work but it fixed my issue, thanks!